# How to read property value of object

Tags: typescript2.0

How can I get the value of object in typescript (.ts file) instead of displaying value on HTML page.
I have stored the values in object called **SelectedUser**, but I want to read the property value **EmailId** of this object.

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'EmailId' of undefined

```ts
checkusernameandpassword(uname: string, pwd: string) {
    if (uname == this.SelectedUser.EmailId && pwd == this.SelectedUser.Password) {
      localStorage.setItem('username', "admin");

      return true;
    }
    else {
      return false;
    }
  }  


checkusernameandpassword(uname: string, pwd: string) {
    if (uname == this.SelectedUser.EmailId && pwd == this.SelectedUser.Password) {
      localStorage.setItem('username', "admin");

      return true;
    }
    else {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Apparently, this issue has nothing to do with typescript but with the fact that `this.SelectedUser` is undefined. Looking at the given code it is impossible to figure out why.

Comment: Try use construction: `if (uname === this.SelectedUser && this.SelectedUser.EmailId && pwd === this.SelectedUser && this.SelectedUser.Password)`